# how to set token expiration time on keycloak

Tags: java, token, keycloak

i have configured keycloak token expiratin, but the result always 3600 second, please help, thank.
[image]

result token expiration always 3600, i am confusing where 3600 come from :
[image]

Comment: I think Keycloak uses 3600 seconds as default as per Oauth standards. Can you try to set different value in your Client -> Settings (tab) -> Advanced Settings (at the bottom) -> Access Token Lifespan and check?

Answer (score 5):

I am able to update the `Access Token Lifespan` at `Realm` Level. Are you updating in proper realm.

[image: Update Token Lifespan]

It is returned properly when i get the access token.

[image: get the Token]

Answer (score -1):

Your Access Token Lifespan is set to 1 min = 3600 seconds. Change it.

Comment: 1 min = 60 seconds, not, 3600 seconds